# Remove wrapping component angular 6

Tags: angular

Im quite new and still learning about angular 6. I`m trying develop dropdown reusable components.

the final syntax **must be**:

```
<ui-select>
  <ui-option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]='team.id'>{{team.value}}</ui-option>
</ui-select>
```

select.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html'
})
export class SelectComponent {


}
```

select.component.html

```
<select class="form-control">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</select>
```

option.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-option',
  templateUrl: './option.component.html'
})
export class OptionComponent {

   @Input()  value:any;

   constructor() {
    this.value = '';
   }

}
```

option.component.html

```
<option [value]="value"><ng-content></ng-content></option>
```

But the final html markdown is incorrect wrapping option inside ui-option component:

```
<ui-select _ngcontent-c0="">
   <select>
  <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"}-->
      <ui-option _ngcontent-c0="" ng-reflect-value="1">
           <option value="1">team 1</option>
      </ui-option>
      <ui-option _ngcontent-c0="" ng-reflect-value="2">
           <option value="2">team 2</option>
      </ui-option>
   </select>
 </ui-select>
```

i want render html like:

```
<ui-select _ngcontent-c0="">
   <select>
  <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"}-->
           <option value="1">team 1</option>
           <option value="2">team 2</option>
   </select>
 </ui-select>
```

How can i get only body ui-option component and render inside select component ?